# Tete-a-tete commonly known in English?

Tags: expressions, american-english, british-english, phrase-usage

Can anyone tell me if the expression "we had a tete-a-tete" or just "tete-a-tete" is commonly known for all English native speakers? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I find it extremely unlikely that every single native English speaker would be familiar with *tete-a-tete*.

Comment: Btw, In the US, "a usually S-shaped seat on which two people can sit so as to face each other." https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tete-a-tete

Comment: Fans of [_The Mikado_](https://books.google.com/books?id=ib8RAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA95&dq=%22tete-a-tetes+insist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_xa3s6JbdAhVD64MKHcoXAs8Q6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=%22tete-a-tetes%20insist%22&f=false) will be familiar with the words of Koko the Lord High Executioner: "And all third persons who on spoiling _tête-à-têtes_ insist— / They'd none of 'em be missed—they'd none of 'em be missed!" But Gilbert and Sullivan enthusiasts are hardly a mass audience these days.

Comment: @Kris I live in the US and have never heard of that ... I would have understood "meeting"

Comment: Being Canadian, I'm very familiar with this French phrase. (Which is a staple of Canadian English.)

Comment: I've certainly been familiar with it since I was a teenager.  And that's been a year or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tete-a-tete is a French expression which is present in all main  English dictionaries

The expression appears to have been more commonly used in the past according to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tete%20a%20tete&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctete%20a%20tete%3B%2Cc0)  probably under the influence of French books popular at that time, but I'd say it is not very common usage nowadays.

According to the [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/tete-a-tete/):

> Tete-a-tete (pronounced tet-uh-tet) comes from the French tête-à-tête, which translates literally to head to head. In English, we use it mainly as:

> - (1) a noun meaning a private conversation between two people,

> - (2) an adjective meaning involving two people conversing in private, and
> - (3) an adverb meaning done in private between two people.

> These are its conventional meanings, anyway. The phrase is also sometimes used to mean a match or competition between two people, and it’s sometimes used to refer to meetings or conversations that are not necessarily private or limited to two people.

> - We usually italicize loanwords and loan phrases that are new to English, but tete-a-tete has been in English for at least three centuries, so it usually goes unitalicized in normal use.

Comment: It is commonly known in British English, at least among reasonably educated speakers.